# Shrinking the size of a 2D array and removing a specific row from it

Tags: c

I am writing a C program where I have two 2d arrays say arr1 & arr2.
I have to remove a specific row from arr1 and add it to arr2. So I used realloc to dynamically increase the size of arr2 by 1 and copied the contents of that row of arr1 to this newly created row of arr2.

But my problem is that I am not able to shrink the size of arr1 and remove that specific row from it by using `realloc`. Can anyone help me out with a C code which can be used to shrink the size of a 2d array dynamically (using `realloc` or something else) and remove a particular row from it (by using the index of that row)?

At first I created the two matrices like this

```
a_seq=(float **)malloc(count1*sizeof(float*));
for(i=0;i<count1;i++)
    a_seq[i]=(float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
```

Then I performed a `realloc` on the 2nd matrix after increasing its size by 1 by

```
a_full=(float **)realloc(a_full,count2*sizeof(float *));
a_full[count2-1]=(float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
for(s=0;s<n;s++)
   a_full[count2-1][s]=a_seq[p][s];
```

p is the index of the row to be deleted from a_seq.My question is that can i apply the same concept of `realloc` to shrink the size of the a_seq matrix and delete the specified row?

Comment: Can you post the code you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you would be allocating memory to your 2d array in the following form :

```
int * arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*r*c);
```

If instead, you allocate memory, row by row, then the problem of deleting a row simplifies.

```
int * arr[r]; /*Declaring an array of pointers*/
/*Allocating memory row by row*/
for(i=0; i<r; i++)       arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*c);

....

/*Row denotes the row to be deleted*/
free(arr[row]);
for(i=row; i<r-1; i++)    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
```

This way you only have the extra pointer left from the pointer array allocation.
The row which you wanted to delete will be successfully deleted.

Comment: At first I created the two matrices like this                      a_seq=(float **)malloc(count1*sizeof(float*));                      
for(i=0;i<count1;i++)
     a_seq[i]=(float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));Then I performed a realloc on the 2nd matrix after increasing its size by 1 by         a_full=(float **)realloc(a_full,count2*sizeof(float *));
a_full[count2-1]=(float *)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
My question is that can i apply the same concept of realloc to shrink the size of the a_seq matrix and delete the specified row?

Comment: @C_beginner Post the code in the question itself. You can edit the question at any point of time.