# C delete a record from struct where dynamic memory allocated

Tags: c, struct, free

using ANSI C and gcc with -Wall -pedantic

I have struct and I pre-populate its data in a loop. Later on I will need to delete a record from it. Let's say record number 3. If I use `free(snode[2]);` would it be enough? Will it decrease the record count automatically?

---

**EDITED**

```
struct stock_data 
{
    int ticket_price;
    int stock_level;
};

typedef struct stock_node 
{
    struct stock_data * data;
} stock_node;

stock_node * snode = NULL;

for(x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
   snode = (stock_node *) realloc(snode, x+1 * sizeof(stock_node));
   if (snode == NULL) { exit(1); }

   snode[x].data = (struct stock_data *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct stock_data));

   snode[count - 1].data->ticket_price = 100;

   snode[count - 1].data->stock_level = 10;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partially free the `malloc`ed memory; for each `malloc` there must be exactly one `free` to free the memory (and it is then freed completely). Indeed, giving `free` an argument other than the same pointer returned by `malloc` or one of the other allocating functions is undefined behaviour.

Also, `malloc` and `free` don't have any knowledge of how you use the memory, so they don't know that you've decided to put an array of `struct coin` in it. `malloc` just gives you a pointer to an area of memory large enough to hold the number of bytes you requested, how you use them is up to you.

**Use a linked list of**, or an array of pointers to, **individually allocated** structs if you need to manage them individually. That is, use a separate `malloc` call to allocate every element in the list or array – note that you must also `free` them all individually, and each exactly once.

Edit: You changed the question to show `realloc` instead of `malloc`. However, the same applies here; you can only `free` the pointer returned by `realloc`, not a part thereof, nor does `free` (or `realloc`) know that you are using the memory for an array of structs. Since you are now `calloc`ing each `data` individually, you *can* (and indeed must) `free` that part individually, but you cannot `free` part of the `realloc`'ed array – you need to clean it up manually after `free`ing the `data` element.

Comment: So, if you try to do it what will happen?

Comment: @digvijay91 You mean what will happen if you try `free(&temp_coin[2])`? The argument of `free` must be the pointer returned by one of the allocating functions – giving it something else is undefined behaviour, i.e., anything could happen (crash, free the whole range, etc). In any case it would not remove that element from the array – `free` and `malloc` have no idea what data is stored in that memory area; to them it is just a range of memory that can be used for “anything”, not an array of structs.

Comment: I have updated the code to clarify the requirement. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

You can only `free()` pointers returned from `malloc()`. If you allocate an array, `struct temp_coin*`, you cannot free parts of it. You have to free the whole array using `free(temp_coin)`.

If you try to free pointers not returned by `malloc()`, bad things will happen like memory corruption and undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

*If I use free(temp_coin[2]); would it be enough?*

No - It is undefined behaviour. What you malloc'ed you need to free. ie. free temp_coin

*Will it decrease the record count automatically?*

There is no record count in the first place

PS you do not need the cast in the malloc

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) if you need that granularity of memory management.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use `free(temp_coin[2]);` would it be enough? Will it decrease the record count automatically?

Of course not. How should it know how to do so? This is C, you have to be very explicit.

As others said, `free()` must exclusively be used for `malloc()`ed areas. Everything else can completely destroy your process's data area - or, for that matter, anything can happen as it is undefinded behaviour.

For example, `free()` might assume that the place before the given address (and BTW, `temp_coin[2]` is not an address, it is a `struct coin`. You are missing a `&` here...) might be the count of bytes allocated. This is true iff its partnering `malloc()` does it define this way. But if you give it any other address, it might add this part to the freelist, leaving the size of the original memory part alone. If you free that then, the freed "sub part" exists twice in the freelist. And then trouble begins.

Instead, you would copy anything behind the item to be removed one step towards the start.
Then you would adjust the number of entries in the list by 1 (wherever you have stored that) and then, potentially now, but maybe later, adjust the size of the allocated memory block to exactly fit the data.

Be aware that calling `realloc()` less often and to preallocate everything in advance might be wiser, depending on the use case. Of course, you have to record the actually allocated size somewhere.

Comment: let's say I freed the record [2] wouldn't be a gap in the array? how will I resize the mem allocation?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was looking for. [Another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169793/shrinking-the-size-of-a-2d-array-and-removing-a-specific-row-from-it)

I should have searched bit more. Sorry for that.

I am assuming you would be allocating memory to your 2d array in the following form :

```
int * arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*r*c);
```

If instead, you allocate memory, row by row, then the problem of deleting a row simplifies.

```
int * arr[r]; /*Declaring an array of pointers*/
```

/*Allocating memory row by row*/

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++)       arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*c);

....
```

/*Row denotes the row to be deleted*/

```
free(arr[row]);
for(i=row; i<r-1; i++)    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
```

Comment: But still something is missing. Okay we free the row from the array. This means that array size reduced by 1. So, don't we need to realloc the allocation to shrink it? Later on, If I want to add a row into the same array, I will need to use realloc to extend the array. How to achieve this without messing.